# Replace any number of white spaces with a single white space

Tags: python, regex, replace

Is there a way to use `replace` with a `regex` denoting any number of any white space (blank but also tab) with something?  I am trying the following to contract any extension of multiple white space to just one but it doesn't work:

```
mystring.replace('\s+', ' ')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use a regular expression in the `replace()` method for strings, you have to use the [re module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re
mystring = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', mystring)
```

Note the `r` prefix before the string literal, this makes sure that the backslash in your regular expressions is interpreted properly.  It wouldn't actually make a difference here, but for different escape sequences it can cause serious problems.  For example `'\b'` is a backspace character but `r'\b'` is a backslash followed by a 'b', which is used for matching word boundaries in regex.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re
result = re.sub('\s+', ' ', mystring)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.split` and `str.join`, to use regex you need [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) :

```
>>> ' '.join('f  o  o\t\t bar'.split())
'f o o bar'
```

Comment: Caveat: this does not work if the string only consists of whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
import re
re.sub('\s+',' ',mystring)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like this.

```
import re
print re.sub(r'\s+', '_', 'hello there')
# => 'hello_there'
```